# Процесс, приоритеты

Tags: windows, прерывания

Допустимо ли изменение в контексте приоритета потока, например: во время прерывания процесса.
Я думаю возможно, если что-то там? И когда?

Например 2 процесса z x. Процесс x прервал процесс z. В контексте процесса z в это время можно изменить приоритет, а это я как понимаю зависит от прав пользователя и может быть от языка. Может кто разбирался в таком? Пример бы какой. Пролистал Рихтера, ничего нужного не нашел по этому.

Comment: Уточните, хотя бы ОС.

Comment: Что именно вы хотели бы изменить в контексте приоритета? О каком прерывании процесса идёт речь, если мы говорим о многопоточном коде?

Comment: Любое прерывание ,при каких условиях возможно изменение самого приоритета

Comment: (1) какая ОС? исходя из Рихтера, Windows? (2) у вас прерывание -- это аппаратное прерывание, или логическое переключение контекста выполнения с одного **потока** на другой? (3) если ваш вопрос на самом деле таков: "можно ли поменять приоритет потока в Windows?", то ответ -- [да](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277.aspx).

Comment: @4namespace4, Вы прерыванием что называете?

Время, когда один пользовательский процесс вытеснил с CPU другой пользовательский процесс?

Или речь об аппаратных прерываниях и потоках ядра?

В любом случае, для ответа желательно знать, **какая ОС** Вас интересует.

Comment: @vladD ос windows . возможны и аппаратное и логическое ,что возможно это я понимаю , там должны соблюдаться какие то условия ,я не понимаю какие ,ну и конечно все зависит от ваших прав ,полномочий .
меня сейчас интересует какой-либо пример .
например при переключении контекста с одно на другой

Comment: @4namespace4: установка приоритета потока и аппаратные прерывания -- вещи полностью ортогональные. По поводу установки приоритета, посмотрите по ссылке в моём предыдущем комментарии.